# Finding correlations between two different pieces of the same column in Power BI

Tags: correlation

Is there a way to find, in Power BI, the correlation between two different pieces of the same column? For example, let's say that the name of the column is "cookie YOY price change", and we have another column containing the kind of cookie, and another column containing the date when the price change was observed. Can Power BI find the correlation between the year-over-year price changes of chocolate chip and peanut butter cookies?
[image]